# Spark: How change DataFrame to LibSVM and perform logistic regression

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, logistic-regression, libsvm

I'm using this code to get data from Hive into Spark:

```
val hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val MyTab = hc.sql("select * from svm_file")
```

and I get DataFrame:

```
scala> MyTab.show()
+--------------------+
|                line|
+--------------------+
|0 2072:1 8594:1 7...|
|0 8609:3 101617:1...|
|            0 7745:2|
|0 6696:2 9568:21 ...|
|0 200076:1 200065...|
|0 400026:20 6936:...|
|0 7793:2 9221:7 1...|
|0 4831:1 400026:1...|
|0 400011:1 400026...|
|0 200072:1 6936:1...|
|0 200065:29 4831:...|
|1 400026:20 3632:...|
|0 400026:19 6936:...|
|0 190004:1 9041:2...|
|0 190005:1 100120...|
|0 400026:21 6936:...|
|0 190004:1 3116:3...|
|0 1590:12 8594:56...|
|0 3632:2 9240:1 4...|
|1 400011:1 400026...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

How can I transform this DataFrame to libSVM to perform logistic regression like in this example: https://altiscale.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202627136-Spark-Shell-Examples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say don't load it into `DataFrame` in the first place and simply use `MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile` but if for some reason this is not on an option you can convert to `RDD[String]` and use the same map logic as used by `loadLibSVMFile`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint

MyTab
  .map{ case Row(line: String) => line }
  .map(_.trim)
  .filter(line => !(line.isEmpty || line.startsWith("#")))
  .map { line => ??? }
```

In place of `???` just copy and paste [a relevant part of the `loadLibSVMFile` method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3cac6614a4fe60b1446bf704d0a35787d385fb86/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/util/MLUtils.scala#L75-L96)

Comment: Works perfect, but can you tell me how can I transform it to `LabeledPoint` ? I'm trying with this code:
`MyTabSVM.map(x => LabeledPoint( x._1, Vectors.sparse( ?, x._2, x._3)))` 
but I'm not sure what should I put for the `?` argument.

Comment: `MyTabSVM.map(_._2.max).max + 1`

Comment: When I'm trying to run a model I get following error:

`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 6.0 (TID 31, hdfs-58.hadoop.srv): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: indices should be one-based and in ascending order`. It albo appears when I want to print the data. Any ideas?

Comment: It suggests you have some malformed entries but without additional I can only guess.

Comment: If your are getting `requirement failed: indices should be one-based and in ascending order` error, then either (1)Your vector dimensions are not sorted in ascending order or (2)your dimensions index is starting from `0` instead of `1`

Answer (score 0):

`sklearn.datasets.dump_svmlight_file` function has a parameter called `zero_based`. It's `True` by default. That means that the indices will start from 0. Spark wants them to start from 1. So: make it `False`.